# Doctrine collection resquest & collection form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

first thanks for your help.

this is my entities :

```
class Salon { 
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Screenfony\DemoBundle\Entity\Exposant", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $exposants;
```

second one :

```
class Exposant{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

I'd like to create a form for an Exposant, who will be able to see the collection of his Salon ( add and remove somes).

First of all i'm stuck on the request to get all salons of an exposant.
i try that but didn't work:

```
    $exposant = $this   ->getDoctrine()
                      ->getManager()
                      ->getRepository('ScreenfonyDemoBundle:Exposant')
                      ->findOneBy(array('user' => $id)); 

    $exposant_id = $exposant->getId();

    $salons = $this ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('ScreenfonyDemoBundle:Salon');

    $my_salons = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); 

    foreach ($salons as $salon) {
        if($salon->getExposants()->contains($exposant_id)){
            $mes_salons->add($salon);
        }
    }
```

and then i would like to add the result in a form and handle the request with the new salons of an exposant.

thanks of your help

Answer (score 0):

In your class exposant, it lacks the relationship many to many that creates the intermediate table `exposant_salon` :

```
class Exposant{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Screenfony\DemoBundle\Entity\salon", inversedBy="exposants", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="exposant_salon",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_exposant", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_salon", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $salons;
```

After create your method getSalons() in your entity exposant :

```
public function getSalons()
{
    return $this->salons;
}
```

to recover an exposant salons do as follows :

```
$my_salons = $exposant->getSalons();
```

Comment: Thanks it works,
now in my FormBuilder i had that
 
->add('salons', 'collection', array(
          'type'         => 'collection',
          'allow_add'    => true,
          'allow_delete'    => true,
      )).   and i can't add any salon in my form

Comment: in your form builder you need a type of entity salon : 

     ->add('salons', 'entity', array(
                'class' => "Screenfony\DemoBundle\Entity\salon",
                'property' => 'nom',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'required' => true
              ))